# Is it possible to run a script on Windows boot as admin by adding it into a "Current Version\Run" registry key of the user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-registry, autorun

This is the Windows **registry autorun key** for my *current* (administrator group) user:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

and this one is for the *"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"* user:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

This is a simple script "Test.cmd" :

```
echo "Hello" >> C:\Test.txt
```

If I add it to the **current user** `Run` key, it works, but if I add it to the **SYSTEM user**, it does not.
What is going on here, and how can I **add a .cmd script** via Windows registry to be executed with the privileges of the user SYSTEM?

Tested on Windows XP, but it would be fine to get some answer for Windows 7 too.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but you're probably not logging on as **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**. I don't even know if that's possible, but you could [try this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcAE37i289w) and see if that works.

Comment: I am not sure about the method you suggest to **add a .cmd script** to the boot sequence of Windows, @Vinayak. The change I have proposed in the registry gest recorded, even between reboots, but the program does not run at all (there is no `C:\Test.txt` file). Are you suggesting to make the changes to the registry after loggin as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`? I think that will make no difference.

Comment: No, I was suggesting that you merely logon as you normally would, then run Task Manager as Administrator and kill Explorer. Then use PsExec to start Explorer under the **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** account to see if the text file gets created then.

Comment: Forget my earlier comment. I think this one might work: Create a scheduled task (Run -> "taskschd.msc") and click the "Change User or Group" button and enter "System" and press OK. Then under "Triggers", create a new trigger and from the "Begin the task" dropdown menu, select "At startup" or "At log on". Could you check if that works?

Comment: @Vinayak, the question refers to registry editing methods. I have edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: Do you wish to simply run a program through your script under the **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** account? That could be done if you're using Windows XP (using the [`AT` command privilege escalation](http://web.cs.du.edu/~ramki/courses/security/forensics/notes/XP%20Privilege%20Escalation.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

I believe your initial question/post is incorrect.  Anything under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE applies *regardless* of the user account used to log in.  So your first statement is incorrect.  Whoever you're logged in as, your Run key would reside under this registry branch:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Additional users would reside under HKEY_USERS.  If you edited the above key while logged in as Administrator, that would also edit the relevant key under HKEY_USERS (since HKCU is just a proxy for one of the entries under HKEY_USERS).

If you place your test.cmd script under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run then it will run no matter which user logs on.  Now your original question in the title says you want to run the command "on Windows boot".  Do you really mean during the boot-up process (i.e. when the Windows logo is showing against a black screen), or do you mean during the *logon* process?

Comment: I meant boot-up process, without any need of logon. The user's HKLM key only runs after it. As long as the user "SYSTEM" does never log in, that could be the problem.
The point of the question was to execute a script as administrator, so the registry edition should be done for the user "SYSTEM".
I have edited the original question to make it clear.